# What are the shortest circuits to sum bits?

Tags: circuit-complexity, hamming-weight

I am interested in circuits that reduce $2^n-1$ input bits into their sum, represented as an $n$ bit integers.  For $n=2$, this is a full adder, which can be implemented with 5 gates of 2 inputs in various ways.  Alternatively, it can be directly implemented using 2 gates of 3 inputs (a parity gate and a majority gate).

For other values of $n$, what are the circuits with lowest gate counts to implement this reduction operation?  I am in particular interested in $n=3$ and $n=4$ and implementations that make use of 2 input gates as well as implementations based on 3 input gates.

The obvious approach is to build a bunch of full adders of course, which e.g. comes out at 11 full adders for $n=4$, giving 55 2-input gates or 22 3-input gates.

Some general literature pointers are be appreciated, too.

Comment: The problem is that at this point in time nobody cares about the shortest circuit, but only about the fastest.

Comment: @gnasher729 In my case the shortest circuit is the fastest as each gate is one machine instruction.  One of the machines can evaluate two 3-input gates in one cycle, the other can evaluate three 2-input gates in one cycle.  So unless the circuit has incredible depth, chances are that only the number of gates matters.

Comment: Which gates do you have available? Any and all?

Comment: Do you have free fan-out?

Comment: @orlp Yes, fan-out is free.

Comment: I was skeptical on how you got to 11 full adders for fully reducing $2^4-1 = 15$ input bits, I had to draw it out, in case anyone else struggles with it: https://i.imgur.com/SnEuwbB.png.

Comment: @orlp You start with 15 bits and end with 4.  Every full adder is a 3-2 reduction, removing one bit from the set.  Hence you need 15 – 4 = 11 of them.

Comment: At least *"The exact multiplicative complexity of the hamming weight function"* by Joan Boyar and René Peralta shows you can't do better than the recursive algorithm of full adders when limited to XOR and AND.

Comment: @orlp Hm... this probably rules out other gates, too.